# My algorithm isn't correct. Why so?

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to solve [the following problem](http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1106):

> The group of people consists of N members. Every member has one or more friends in the group. You are to write program that divides this group into two teams. Every member of each team must have friends in another team.
>
> **Input:**
>   The first line of input contains the only number N (N ≤ 100). Members are numbered from 1 to N. The second, the third,…and the (N+1)th line contain list of friends of the first, the second, …and the Nth member respectively. This list is finished by zero. Remember that friendship is always mutual in this group.
>
> **Output:**
>   The first line of output should contain the number of people in the first team or zero if it is impossible to divide people into two teams. If the solution exists you should write the list of the first group into the second line of output. Numbers should be divided by single space. If there are more than one solution you may find any of them.

My algorithm looks like this:

```
create a dictionary where each player maps to a list of friends

team1 = ['1']
team2 = []

left = []

for player in dictionary:
    if its friend in team1:
        add to team2
    elif its freind in team2:
        add to team1
    else:
        add it to left
```

But still it isn't correct. There may be cycles in the dictionary where the friend of 6 would be 7 and the only friend of 7 would be 6. What should I do in such a case? I do not know how long such a cycle may be. What should I do. Since, I have a while loop around my code, I currently am running into an infinite loop. I am also trying to add players from `left` to teams but its not working since they have cycles among them. I don't know how to solve the following problem.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `left` list?

Comment: @exilit It's purpose is to store the players that currently do not have any friends in either team.

Comment: have you consider the case "it is impossible to divide people into two teams"

Comment: Isn't the whole point of attempting this sort of competition problem to figure out and implement a good algorithm? I mean, suppose someone here suggests an ingenious algorithm; what then? how are you any better off? I'm sorry if this seems rude; I'm just trying to understand what the real goal is...

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Learning new things. How will I improve if I leave the problems I can't answer unseen?

Comment: Kit Fung, if everyone in the group has at least one friend in the group (guaranteed by the problem statement) then there is always a way to assign people to teams that meets the conditions.

Comment: @Lafexlos It's there in my code but I didn't insert it in the pseudocode.

Comment: Get rid of the left list and put a player that has no friends in team1 and team2 to team1.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan What if there are 3 players?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I don't think so. See, if there are 3 people -1, 2 and 3. 1's friends is 2, 2's is 3 and 3's is 1. A cycle of 3 has no solutions. A cycle of any odd number won't work.

Comment: @exilit, in that case the only configurations meeting the conditions are 1-2-3 and 1-2-3-1. In either case you can put 1,3 in team 1 and 2 in team 2.

Comment: Oh, have I misunderstood the problem statement? I took it to mean: everyone has at least one friend in the other team.

Comment: Is it actually meant to mean "everyone has friends *only* in the other team" or something? The problem statement is really unclear.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I think it means that everyone has *atleast 1* friend.

Comment: So if you look at the linked page there's an example, and it fits the "everyone has at least one friend in the other team" interpretation and *not* "everyone has friends only in the other team". So a cycle of length 3 is fine: pick one to be on team 2 and put the others on team 1 and all is well.

Comment: Oh -- did you miss the fact that friendship is symmetrical? "Remember that friendship is always mutual in this group."

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Oh! So, I can update the dictionary with mutual friendships.

Comment: Sebastian's proposal looks too simple-minded, but it actually works in all cases.

Comment: It's not mentioned that the teams should be equal, so making a team of one and a team of N-1 is already a solution.

Comment: @bereal True. I'll try it and report.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a competition problem and it's clear you want to learn from it, I'll be a little sparse on details and explain more about how I thought about the problem.

First, consider a connected friendship component, then pick any vertex. Since the friendship relationship is commutative, it's easy to see that adding an edge means that both the vertices are "solved". This seems to suggest something like finding a [perfect matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)).

However, finding a perfect matching is not sufficient, as for the complete graph with three vertices, a perfect matching doesn't exist, yet it can be solved. So thinking about it little more, it seems that a [Hamiltonian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) is sufficient, because you can just alternate teams.

If you consider a sufficiently large tree though, it should be clear that there's no Hamiltonian path, but the obvious splitting of teams by even or odd height produces the right result. So the answer seems to be that if you can find a spanning tree, that tree can be used to split the teams into two.

This can be repeated for each component, and just playing around with graphs, it should be convincing enough for a competition, as every component has a spanning tree, so there's nowhere else to expand to. I'm not sure what would be a graph with no possible assignment. Maybe if you have an unconnected node, that's considered invalid?

Answer (score 1):

**Update: I found even simpler solution. The original answer is at the bottom. This one is cleaner and comes with a proof ;)**

We will be building the solution incrementally. The initial state is that all the people are unallocated, and both teams are empty. We will extend the solution using one of two actions below. After each step, the division will be legal, meaning every allocated person will have a friend allocated to the other team.

**Action 1:** pick any two unallocated guys that are friends. Put one of them in Team A, the other in Team B. The invariant holds, because newly allocated people know each other and are on separate teams.

**Action 2:** pick any guy who has an allocated friend, and place him on the other team. The invariant holds, because the one allocated person was allocated in such a way to satisfy it.

So at very step you pick any doable action and execute it. Repeat until there are no more possible actions. When does this happen? It would mean that no-one of the unallocated people has any friends. Since we assumed that everyone has at least one friend, you will be able to execute the actions until there is nobody left.

**Original answer:**

The problem seems complicated at first, but in fact does not require rocket science. The constraint on the division is rather loose - everyone needs just one friend on the other team.

Consider a simpler case first. Let's say you are given two teams of people and one extra player that got late to the party and needs to be allocated to one of the two existing teams. If he has no friends at all, that's impossible. But if he does have any friends, you pick one of his friends and allocate the newcommer to the other team.

The outcome? If you could start with some small teams and then arrange the rest of the people in such a way that they always know someone who came before, you're golden. This means we reduced initial big problem to two smaller ones.

Tackling the first one is easy. In order to bootstrap the teams, just pick any two guys that know each other, put one in Team A, the other in Team B, and it works.

Now, the second: adding the rest of the people. Take a look at all the people that are already allocated to teams and see if they have any unallocated friends. Case 1: one of already allocated guys has an unallocated friend. You can easily add him somewhere. Case 2: all the friends of the allocated guys are already allocated, too. This means the initial friendship graph was not connected and doesn't hurt at all - just take any random unallocated guy and place him anywhere.